# Apache 2.4 config include files appear to be ignored

Tags: include, config, apache2.4

I have an apache2 site config that works perfectly. When I place some of the directives into an include file the rewrites are no longer processed.

1. They all work when in a single conf file.
2. mod_info http://{server name}/server-info shows the directives loaded when either a single file or with include files.
3. If an include file has the wrong name or wrong permissions apache2 fails at start.
4. Single conf file or with multiple includes passes apachectl -t syntax check.

Example code is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.....
include  /etc/apache2/includes/site80.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

site80.conf has:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* - [E=junk:1,L]
```

I can find nothing else required to make the includes work, and apache appears to load them according to mod_info.

Can anyone shed any light why the includes appear to be ignored?

Thanks